# Prevent automatic addition of BOM to bytearray

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, arrays, python-unicode

I'm tearing my hair out on this one.

I have a bytearray:

```
output = bytearray()
```

and I have a memoryview, mapped over a bytearray read from a file:

```
ba = bytearray(os.path.getsize(filename))
with open(filename, 'rb') as fin:
    fin.readinto(ba)
mv = memoryview(ba)
```

Now, I do this:

```
output += mv[pos:pos + length]
```

But... that adds a 3-byte BOM to the beginning of the bytearray!

I've tried everything I can think of, for example, `output = bytearray('', encoding='cp437')` but that godforsaken BOM still appears!

How the heck can I prevent this automatic addition of BOM?

Comment: It sounds like this file just has a BOM at the start of it, and Python is correctly reading the BOM out of the file.

Comment: Nope. The binary file begins with \x50\xFB. At the location of [pos], it has the value \x01. No BOM that I can see.

Comment: How do you know the BOM is being added to the bytearray in `output += mv[pos:pos + length]`, and how do you know that the file doesn't have a BOM? Have you determined at what point your program goes from not having a BOM in any data structures to having a BOM somewhere? Can you show a minimal script and file that produces the error?

Comment: This behavior came to my attention when comparing the total length of output after processing, the length is 3 bytes longer than the reference. Checking the first 3 bytes by iteration got me \xEF \xBB \xBF. Sadly I've reverted my code to using BytesIO which does not exhibit this exasperating behavior.

Comment: The file is guaranteed not to have a BOM; I've opened it using a hex editor.

Comment: There is no manipulation of output except by the above line of output += mv[...], but when processing finished, output is always longer by 3 bytes compared to the reference.

Comment: The docstring of `readinto` is `"readinto() -> Undocumented.  Don't use this; it may go away."` It might just be that `readinto` doesn't fully work, or doesn't behave the way you'd expect.

Comment: That doesn't explain why if, instead of using bytearray I use BytesIO (replacing += with .write), the BOM doesn't appear.

Comment: @user2357112:  [The method is documented in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.readinto). It is unlikely that it goes away in Python 2.

Comment: If you think that `output += mv..` line adds BOM; could you create a minimal example that shows it: e.g., `output = bytearray(); mv = memoryview(bytearray(b'\x50\xfb')); output += mv[0:2]; print(output)` shows `bytearray(b'P\xfb')` (no BOM as expected).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although the problem is reproducible, it was due to external factors (in this case, wrong reference file for testing). It was my mistake, so please close this question to prevent others from wasting their time on this.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, first of all, I'd like to apologize to all who had joined this wild goose chase. The mistake was mine, and not Python's.

Let me explain:

We have two directories, `STAGING` and `DEV`. The former representing code that runs well (and suitable to hand over to QA), the latter contains code in development and probably buggy. Only after passing a battery of tests will code 'graduate' from DEV to STAGING.

The code in STAGING uses the `io.BytesIO` mechanism I've mentioned in my comments to the question. The code in DEV replaces BytesIO with `bytearray`.

Someone in the team inadvertently replaced a pair of test files, let's call them `test-input` and `test-reference`. So, we now have two pairs of test files: `STAGING/test-input`, `STAGING/test-reference`, `DEV/test-input`, and `DEV/test-reference`.

Now, the **comedy of errors** begins.

The `test-` pair in STAGING are pure binary files. When asked by @user2357112 in the comments above, I was checking the `test-` file in STAGING. So, no BOM there.

**BUT**, the `test-` pair in DEV is totally different. The input is binary, but the output **is XML**. And the teammember extracted the XML file using a 3rd party tool *which stripped out the BOM*.

I found out about this when, diffing between STAGING and DEV, I found that the size of the `test-` file pairs *are different*.

So, I hijacked the proven-correct functions in STAGING to properly decompress the `DEV\test-input` file... and whaddaya know! It has BOM!!

(In defense of the team member, the newer `test-` file pair *is* larger, about 3x the size of the 'original' `test-` file pair, so it *should* be better to catch edge cases)

We lost one day of productivity because of this stupid mistake >.<

To prevent similar incident from happening, we're instating the following:

- All test files will be `chmod 0444` to prevent overwriting.
- The team's policy will be updated to explicitly forbid replacing known-good test files.
- The team member making the mistake will be forced to treat the team to 1 pint of beer, each :-)

Again, thank you for your kind help. I apologize for your wasted time.